# jquery Focus Callback

Tags: jquery

Can somebody please tell me why this isnt working?

```
$("textarea.settings").focus(function () {
            var size = $(this).height();
            console.log(size);
            if(size == 40) {$(this).animate({height: 120},"slow");} 
        }, function () {
            $(this).animate({height: 40},"slow");
        });
```

please tell me why?

Comment: `focus` doesn't accept 2 callbacks.

Comment: What's it supposed to do? What is is actually doing?

Comment: increase the size when the user clicks on it, decrease when they click off.

Comment: @undefined I'm sure i've used it before :|

Comment: @Chud37 - Then I'm sure you've mistaken, as focus does not have 2 callbacks, you'll need blur().

Comment: @Chud37 You may be confusing it with `.hover()`, which does take two callbacks that it binds to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`focus()` doesn't accept 2 parameters. Use `blur()` if your intention is for on/off focus:

```
$("textarea.settings").focus(function () {
    var size = $(this).height();
    console.log(size);
    if(size == 40) {$(this).animate({height: 120},"slow");} 
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).animate({height: 40},"slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/iquhoq/4/edit)*

```
$("textarea.settings").on('focus blur',function (e) {
    var isFocus = e.type=='focus',
        animH = isFocus? 120 : 40;
    $(this).animate({height: animH}, 800);
});
```

You could list your events inside `.on([events list])`
than setting a boolean variable (`isFocus`) you can play with your sizes using a `ternary operator` and animate respectively.